# Pyvisa - Pyusb fails to load sequences larger than 1 MB

Tags: python, pyusb, pyvisa

I am connecting via USB to an Agilent (33600) waveform generator. If the waveform I am sending is less than 1MB (2^20 bytes) it works perfectly. If it is larger it hangs and fails at timeout.

Using:

- Python3.7, Pyusb 1.1, Pyvisa 1.11 with Pyvisa-py 0.5.1 backend. Tried both Linux Mint and Raspberry Pi 4.

Minimum working example:

```py
import pyvisa as visa

my_WFM = 262000*[1] # works fine 262000*4 = 1,048,000
#my_WFM = 263000*[1] # fails (it is just above 1MB) 263000*4 = 1,052,000

resources = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
devices = resources.list_resources()
my_device = resources.open_resource(devices[1])
print(my_device.query('*IDN?')) # works fine

## Prepare the device
my_device.timeout = 300000
my_device.write('*CLS;*RST')
tmp = my_device.query('*OPC?')
my_device.write('SOURce1:DATA:VOLatile:CLEar')

## Send the waveform
my_device.write('FORM:BORD NORM') # set the byte order
bytes_sent = my_device.write_binary_values('SOUR1:DATA:ARB myARB,', my_WFM,datatype='f', is_big_endian=True)
print(bytes_sent)
my_device.write('*WAI') # Wait for the waveform to load

print(my_device.query('SYSTEM:ERROR?')) # no errors for less than 1MB

my_device.close() # close connection to device
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to poll the device to see if the action has been completed rather than wait for the action to complete. Try using the "*OPC?" command in a loop like the example I have below.

```
import pyvisa as visa
from time import sleep

my_WFM = 262000*[1] # works fine 262000*4 = 1,048,000
#my_WFM = 263000*[1] # fails (it is just above 1MB) 263000*4 = 1,052,000

resources = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
devices = resources.list_resources()
my_device = resources.open_resource(devices[1])
print(my_device.query('*IDN?')) # works fine

## Prepare the device
my_device.timeout = 300000
my_device.write('*CLS;*RST')
tmp = my_device.query('*OPC?')
my_device.write('SOURce1:DATA:VOLatile:CLEar')

## Send the waveform
my_device.write('FORM:BORD NORM') # set the byte order
bytes_sent = my_device.write_binary_values('SOUR1:DATA:ARB myARB,', my_WFM,datatype='f', is_big_endian=True)
print(bytes_sent)
device_operation_complete = 0
while not device_operation_complete:
    device_operation_complete = my_device.query('*OPC?') #should return a 1 if complete
    sleep(2)


print(my_device.query('SYSTEM:ERROR?')) # no errors for less than 1MB

my_device.close() # close connection to device
```